# solve a game matrix (zero-sum)

Tags: game-theory

Consider the game matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 &-1
\\ 
 -1 & -1 &2 
\\
 5 & -1 &-1
\end{bmatrix}

Is there any way to reduce it into 2x3 or 3x2 matrix(I don't see a dominating row or column here)? I know how to use the simplex method to solve it but am trying make it simpler.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no dominating row or column here

Comment: I don't know how much this helps you as I do not know much about game theory, but I have been trying to mess with this problem. Try checking what I have below.
$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ 
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\ 
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1+b_1 & a_2+b_2 & a_3+b_3 \\ 
b_1+c_1 & b_2+c_3 & b_3+c_3 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1+a_2 & a_2+a_3\\ 
b_1+b_2& b_2+b_3\\ 
c_1+c_2 & c_2+c_3 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
,
C = c_3
$

And if we solve for each variable using reduced row echelon form and the initial condition that the...

Comment: $c_3 = C$, we are able to find every variable without data loss. And what is even better is that there are 9 variables, so we can reduce the 3x2 matrix into a 3x1 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after putting the question asides for a while and coming back, I suddenly noticed a special feature in the matrix, Adding 1 to every entry and rearranging the rows, we will get

\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 0 &0
\\ 
 0 & 2 &0 
\\
 0 & 0 &3
\end{bmatrix}

Now, its a diagonal matrix and the maximin strategy is simply normalised 
$$
(1/6, 1/2, 1/3)
$$
which , after rearranging back to the original order, is the maximin strategy of the original game.

The minimax strategy and the value can be easily computed.

I actually don't know why I did not see it at the first glance and why I saw this suddenly. I guess it's the tricky beauty of Maths that we all love :)